# Error when using closure to make an accumulator call

Tags: closures

Ideal state output 1，2，3，4，5，6，7，8 
Why can't I transfer counter()?
Does the boss explain it?

```js
function add() {
        var count = 0;
        function demo() {
          count ++;
          console.log(count);
        }
        return demo();
      }

      var counter = add();
      counter();
      counter();
      counter();
      counter();
      counter();
      counter();
      counter();
      counter();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function add() {
        var count = 0;
        function demo() {
          count ++;
          console.log(count);
        }
        return demo;
      }

      var counter = add();
      counter();
      counter();
      counter();
      counter();
      counter();
      counter();
      counter();
      counter();
```